# In CSS, how to retrieve the color of the 2nd degree parent?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this html code:

```
some text, blablabla
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hola</li>
</ul
```

And I need to color the dots of the list in blue with a bigger size, but I also need the text of the list to stay as it is (same font, color and size as "some text, blablabla").

So I tried to use a `span` tag like this,

```
some text, blablabla
<ul>
<li style="color: #00B0F0;font-size: 200%;"><span style="font-size: 100%;color:default;">hello</span></li>
<li style="color: #00B0F0;font-size: 200%;"><span style="font-size: 100%;color:default;">hola</span></li>
</ul>
```

But, it does not work, i.e the text in the list is the same color as the dots (blue).

So, I must find a way to apply the color of the text before the list to the text of the list (knowning that I don't know the text properties that I want to apply, I am just applying a specific font). 
Any idea ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: no inline css!!! bad practice! also default isn't a real css property.. just put it to #000?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `color:initial` & `font-size: 50%` for span tag.. check below snippet

```html
some text, blablabla
<ul>
    <li style="color: #00B0F0;font-size: 200%;"><span style="font-size: 50%; color: initial;">hello</span></li>
    <li style="color: #00B0F0;font-size: 200%;"><span style="font-size: 50%; color: initial;">hola</span></li>
</ul>
```

**or you can do this using CSS `content` property **

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
    padding-left: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

li::before {
    content: "• ";
    color: red;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>hola</li>
    <li>hola</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, I think I did not explain correctly, the text before the list has a specific color (which is not the default ont), so if I use your code, the text in the list will be the default one, but I want it to be the same color as I used for "some text, blablabla"

Comment: @aurelSon then create a class called .fontColor and assign a color to it..

Comment: But I don't know the color of the text before the list, I just applied a font called "Comfortaa Regular" to it

Comment: @aurelSon in my second snippet i have created same thing using css without passing color on text.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use css `content` and display bullets list as per your requirement.Like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "•";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: blue;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see an example here:  https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html

li::before {content: "•"; color: red}